# MAX_SIZE OF SET

Tags: stl

IS THE MAX_SIZE OF A SET IS ALWAYS CONSTANT?IF YES THEN WHAT IS THE VALUE OF IT?

Answer (score 0):

No.  Each set has a call `max_size()` which gives you the maximum theoretical size of the set.  However, there are usually other constraints (such as the amount of memory in the machine) that will (probably) limit the growth of the set before it reaches `max_size()`.